# Selenium web driver login third party website problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

I am trying to login into a third party system, for example, facebook.com by sending the username and password from my personal web application developed in asp.net web form. I am able to execute below code locally and able to login into it, but when I host my application in the cloud, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what could be the issue: Below is my code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("test-type");
options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("chromedriver.exe");

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
{
driver.Url = "www.facebook.com";
driver.FindElementById("xxxxx").SendKeys("value");
driver.FindElementById("xxxxxx").SendKeys("value");
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Button--login")).Click();
driver.Navigate();
};
```

Any alternative way out to achieve this functionality also will be much appreciated.